# Is a *self-contradictory self-referential* statement false?

Tags: logic

Fitch concludes in his paper "A Goedelized formulation of the prediction paradox" that the following is a self-contradictory self-referential statement:

P: The prisoner will be hanged next week and its date will not be deducible the night before using this statement as an axiom.

Let's assume that this statement is false, no matter what the hanging day is. A judge has said this statement to two prisoners, and has chosen Monday and Tuesday as the hanging days.

Prisoner 1 is hanged on Monday, then ~P implies that it's deducible from P that the hanging day is Monday.

Prisoner 2 is hanged on Tuesday, then ~P implies that it's deducible from P that the hanging day is Tuesday.

It's a contradiction. Where's the fault?

Comment: The usual end of this puzzle is that one derives (using the part after the "and" of the axiom and that the prisoner will not be hanged after next week) that the prisoner will not be hanged next week. Consequently, the actual execution on Wednesday, say, does come as a surprise - as postulated.

Comment: With "self-contradictory" do you mean that it has a form of "self-reference" ? Because often we use "self-contradictory" to mean simply "contradictory". In this case: YES, a contradictory statement is **always** false.

Comment: Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA, I edited. I think you can post your comment as an answer, and I will check mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We often use "self-contradictory" to mean simply "contradictory".

In this case: yes, a contradictory statement is **always** false.

If with "self-contradictory" we assume some form of "self-reference", we have to consider that [self-reference](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-reference/) is a thorny issue:

> In the context of language, *self-reference* is used to denote a statement that refers to itself or its own referent. The most famous example of a self-referential sentence is the liar sentence: “This sentence is not true.”

Thus, if with "self-contradictory" we mean the paradigmatic [Liar-example](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/) :

> "This sentence is not true",

the answer is that both assumptions about its truth-value lead to contradiction.